# How do i declare two "res" in params using getInitialProps and NextPageContext in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here is my code for getting data in server using getInitialProps. But as you can see, there is two res params declared with different purpose. How can i declare it or separate it? I got an error duplicate res declared.

```
ProductDetails.getInitialProps = ({res}, res: NextPageContext) => {
  const productModel = _.get(res, 'locals.productModel', {});
  const isMobile = _.get(res, 'locals.isMobile', false);
  const { query: { data }, } = res;
  return {
    page: { ...(data as Model)?.page } || emptyModel,
    ...productModel,
    isMobile,
  };
};
```

Comment: `getInitialProps` only receives a single context object which in turn contains a single `res` object. That second `res` is always undefined.

Comment: Can i declare two getInitialProps in parent component?

Comment: You can't declare two `getInitialProps` for the same page. Why would you want to do that? What's the use case?

Comment: because there is different value for res and res:NextPageContext. The first res is for productModel and second res:NextPageContext is for query

Comment: Are you explicitly passing those two `res` to your pages `getInitialProps` from somewhere? You can always rename one of them like: `({ res: modelRes }, res: NextPageContext)`.

Comment: Yes, i already tried that, changed the name of other res but it shows some error of "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined".

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, unless you are explicitly passing those two res to your pages `getInitialProps`, that second `res` is always undefined.

Comment: is there a way that the res server response will not undefined?

Comment: I recommend you have a read through [`getInitialProps` docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps).

Comment: All good thanks. I resolved the issue.